# Why am I not being notified when my posts are edited?

Tags: support, bug, editing

About an hour ago [one of my answers](https://serverfault.com/a/633400/126632) was edited.

[image: SF answer that was edited]

However, I didn't get a notification of the edit in my inbox.

[image: Global inbox]

I spoke to some other users, who told me they *are* receiving notifications of edited posts. So I suspect it's something in particular with my account, my settings, or something utterly stupid that I did while completely smashed one weekend and forgot about.

Whatever it is, I'd love to start getting these notifications again.

---

After some testing, I determined that I *am* getting notices for *suggested edits*, but not for edits made by 3K+ users.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is by design. I have never received notifications of edits to my content, only ever suggested edits.

You can see edit list under Responses > Revisions in your profile:

[image]

Comment: Some of your revision descriptions are hilarious. Mine are all full of "typo", "mixed up X and Y", "typo", and "grammar".